# Bcrypt is generating an invalid password when encoding in Spring boot (Encoded password does not look like BCrypt)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm designing an api REST with register/login funcinality using Spring boot 3.1.0 and Spring Security 6.1 but it seems like bcrypt is not able to generate a proper password. Filters are properly set, but when I encode a password I get an incorrect one.

Config class:

```
package cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.config;

import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.controllers.PlayerNotFoundException;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.repositories.PlayerRepositoryMySQL;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final PlayerRepositoryMySQL playerRepositoryMySQL;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService () {
        return username -> {
            try {
                return playerRepositoryMySQL.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(PlayerNotFoundException::new);
            } catch (PlayerNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Service layer:

```
package cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.auth;

import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.config.JwtService;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.controllers.PlayerNotFoundException;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.domain.Role;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.repositories.PlayerRepositoryMySQL;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.domain.Player;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final PlayerRepositoryMySQL playerRepositoryMySQL;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {
        Optional<List<Player>> playerRetrievedOptional = playerRepositoryMySQL.getPlayersByName(request.getName());
        if (!playerRetrievedOptional.get().isEmpty() && (playerRetrievedOptional.get().stream().anyMatch(player -> !player.getName().equals(Player.DEFAULT_NAME)) || playerRetrievedOptional.get().stream().anyMatch(player -> player.getEmail().equals(request.getEmail())))) {
            return null;
        } else {
            var encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword());
            System.out.println(encodedPassword);
            var player = Player.builder()
                    .name(request.getName())
                    .dateOfRegistration(Player.dateSetter())
                    .email(request.getEmail())
                    .password(encodedPassword)
                    .role(Role.USER)
                    .build();
            playerRepositoryMySQL.save(player);
            var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(player);
            return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                    .token(jwtToken)
                    .build();

        }
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) throws PlayerNotFoundException {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()));
        var player = playerRepositoryMySQL.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).orElseThrow(PlayerNotFoundException::new);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(player);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Controller layer:

```
package cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.auth;

import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.llombartroma.toni.s05.t02.n01.S05T02N01LlombartRomaToni.controllers.PlayerNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dicegame/player/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService service;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AuthenticationController(AuthenticationService service, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.service = service;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword());
        request.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) throws PlayerNotFoundException {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
    }
}
```

For instance, i'm getting the word "sunscreen" encoded like $2a$10$inwBiCPtEwrK7RZG8zw53OjxdIKiNsMXetMhiYFFvKNVCsTBjUry6, which is not a valid BCrypt. As a consequence, I'm lead to Encoded password does not look like BCrypt error when authenticate method is called.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are encoding the password twice, Once in controller and another in service. make it a habit to keep all your business logic in service layer to avoid such bugs in the future.
so the solution is to remove encoding line from AuthController

Comment: Thank you @AhmedNabil! That was the issue, indeed. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @Ketterle always happy to help :) I am currently learning spring security as well (it's a hell of a project) with so many classes and injections :D

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue using 5.7.8

```
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-crypto', version: '5.7.8'
```

Code:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("sunscreen"));
}
```

Output:

```
$2a$10$t9.627zJ93ekvIZ/QBxV7eg.fl2I1QGOC8sM9vZnX85Ep6GlluY3G
```

Check using https://bcrypt.online/

[image: hash verification]